# Avoid quotes when using CMake to pass a process output as compile options for specific target

Tags: cmake, quotes

I have a problem with CMake:
I use `execute_process()` to set a variable and I want that variable to pass it as options to the compiler.
CMake sets quotes around the variable so that the compiler gets wrong input.

Concretely: I need to compile SDL2 with only a specific target.

```
# CMakeLists.txt
execute_process(COMMAND "sdl2-config" "--cflags" OUTPUT_VARIABLE SDL2_CFLAGS OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
target_compile_options(SpecialTarget PUBLIC ${SDL2_CFLAGS})
```

The output of `sdl2-config --cflags` is:

```
-I/usr/include/SDL2 -D_REENTRANT
```

CMake calls the compiler now in this way:

```
/usr/bin/c++ ... "-I/usr/include/SDL2 -D_REENTRANT" ...
```

Of course this does not work. I need to get rid of the quotes.

If a use

```
add_definitions(${SDL2_CFLAGS})
```

everything works. But I need `target_compile_options` because I want the options not on all targets.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`separate_arguments`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/command/separate_arguments.html) command:

```
separate_arguments(SDL2_CFLAGS UNIX_COMMAND "${SDL2_CFLAGS}")
target_compile_options(SpecialTarget PUBLIC ${SDL2_CFLAGS})
```

Comment: So when I do this, I get bogus output. My input looks something like, "-I/foo/bar   -I/foo/baz/ -I/usr/foo" (note the extra whitespace) and separate_arguments returns something like "-I/foo/bar/-I/foo/baz/ -I/usr/foo". In other words, it seems to take multiple spaces and remove them entirely, leaving behind a mangled include_directories() list. Any ideas?